# dividing several img tags in string

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"assets/images/1.jpg;assets/images/2.jpg;assets/images/3.jpg";
```

how can i create an array that pushes each link in it and removes the ;?

something like this:

```
var images:Array = {assets/images/1.jpg,assets/images/2.jpg,assets/images/3.jpg};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
s = "assets/images/1.jpg;assets/images/2.jpg;assets/images/3.jpg";
a = s.split(";");
```

http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary696.html

Comment: offcourse, i was allready thinking about a regex , making it to dificult again, tyvm